# SQL Server Output to Text File Each Column Different Length Space Delimited

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a SQL Server table that looks like the following:

```
ID             NAME                DESCRIPTION
1              ANDREW              COOL
2              MATT                NOT COOL
```

All I need to do is output the data to a space delimited text file.  However I want to ensure that the 'NAME' column has at maximum 10 characters.  So for example with the first row 'ANDREW' is is 6 characters, then I'd want 4 spaces after it.

Same thing for second row.  'MATT' is 4 characters, so I would want 6 spaces after it.  This way as you move to each column the data is lined up, worst case it gets truncated but I'm not concerned with that.

Answer (score 4):

Use this select query then export this to ur text file.

```
select ID,cast(NAME as char(10)) as NAME,DESCRIPTION from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks...! however it still puts 1 space in between each column on the output.  Is that an easy fix?

Comment: i did not get your question here? see above statement will have to have 10 characters always for name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use convert function

```
select CONVERT(char(10),'ANDREW')
```

.

```
select ID,
       CONVERT((char(10),NAME) as NAME,
       DESCRIPTION 
from <table>
```